# Need assistance in making password database

Tags: javascript, database, html, authentication

I have looked everywhere but cannot find an answer. I will change my code if I have have to, but I hopefully won't have too, so If you can you give me an answer in JavaScript that would be great. 
I am attempting to make a password database for this code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>   <title>login2</title>   <meta charset="utf-8" /> </head> <body> <input class="textBox" id="pass" type="password" maxlength="30" required/> <button type="button" onclick="a()">Login</button> <script>
    function a() {
        var i = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        if (i == "1234") {
            window.location = "in.html";
        } 
        else {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }
    } </script> </body> </html>
```

I want to make it so instead of saying `if (i == "1234)` I can get a value from an external database, with a list of passwords.
If you can please tell me how to modify the contents!

Thanks, Please help!

Comment: you wouldn't do this in javascript

Comment: This shouldn't be done on the client side using JavaScript. You need a web server and should use a language like PHP to deal with the login. Otherwise users could easily grab that list of passwords.

Also, make sure to look up password hashing.

Comment: This should be done predominantly in PHP.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL is a solid starting point

Comment: You will have to use some sort of server-side code along with a database.  It doesn't appear to me that you have either.  There's a lot to choose from:  you could use PHP or ASP.NET for your server-side code, then MySQL or Microsoft SQL for the database.  If you want to stick with JavaScript - then you could use node.js for your server-side code and maybe PostgreSQL for the database.  You really need to choose a platform first, then we could help more.

Comment: @Orpheus: _predmoninantly_ is absolutly (to keep up with your exaggeration) wrong. Any serverside language is suitable for this task. EthanManzi: Take a break and have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php

Comment: What kind of database are you looking to use?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am a very bad coder, and I don't really want to learn a new code. All I'm really asking is this: Is there any for my JavaScript code to access a 'table' with passwords, and maybe usernames, within it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest doing, and have done in the past is by storing hashes in  memory rather than the password(s). You could implement a version of [Joseph Myers's MD5 script](https://github.com/wbond/md5-js), then modify the contents of the `<script>` tag to match the following:

```
var i = document.getElementById('pass').value;
if (md5(i) == "##MD5ofExpectedPassword##") {
    window.location = i+".html"; // Change the name of the page to the password
} else {
    window.location = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: Password validation does not belong on the client! https://www.owasp.org/index.php

Comment: I very well understand that password validation should not be processed by the client, and instead should be sent to the server. However if, like me, your host does not support server-side scripting, this is a very valid, and decently secure method. This method was only supposed to be used in this case. Sorry for any confusion. I was simply answering the question that Ethan asked to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: _decently secure method_? View source and et voilà. Furthermore he mentions a database so there must be a server.

Comment: View source and you still wouldn't have the password. Look at the code. You'd only have the MD5 hash of the password.

Comment: 1. md5 is unsafe/broken. 2. I don't need the password at all, as I can see the source of the function and therefore can do what it would do after a successful authentication. Client-side authentication is useless...

Comment: 1. Although there are many MD5 tables out there, crackers exist, and MD5 is easily brute-forceable and not birthday paradox safe, MD5 is a simple and fast solution for weak security. You could always change the hashing method to increase the security.  2. Even after a successful authentication, you see that you would need the original password to be able to navigate successfully to the success page.

Comment: Look, all I know is that helped a bit, and no, I don't have server. I local-host or use noip to 'wamp' a site. Thank you fond42518! Still was a bit confusing for me, and still trying to figure it out, but it makes sense, so it **Will** work?! The rest of you, he answered my question, so stop yelling at him, you dislike his method, rewrite something yourself!